# React Native webview cookies issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I have a issue in webview not being able to set cookies on iOS.

Am implementing third party payment gateway in a webview And when the user got redirected to the result page, i got a message saying that "cookies are not enabled in the browser "

So how to enable cookies in webview on iOS?

Comment: Have you get a solution? I am running into the same error on my RN WebView on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

In react native webview cookies are default enable please check following link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html

```
thirdPartyCookiesEnabled?: bool 

Boolean value to enable third party cookies in the WebView. 
Used on Android Lollipop and above only as third party cookies are enabled by
default on Android Kitkat and below and on iOS. The default value is true.


<WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
        thirdPartyCookiesEnabled : true
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use property **sharedCookiesEnabled={true}** in webView.
Its working in myCase